# Setting for hostAliases in jenkins helm

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Jenkins using helm.
agetn to be dynamically created under additionalAgents was declared.
Each agent needs to register hosts for the domain gitlab.cicd.kr in order to visit Gitlab.
I don't know how.
There is no such content in the official document.

```
additionalAgents:
  maven:
    podName: maven
    customJenkinsLabels: maven
    # An example of overriding the jnlp container
    # sideContainerName: jnlp
    image: jenkins/jnlp-agent-maven
    tag: latest
```